# What is the output of git subtree push and how can I make it faster?

Tags: git, git-subtree

When executing git subtree push, the application outputs a series of numbers, which seem to continuously increase as the number of commits to the repo increase. The problem that this causes is that pushing subtree changes take a really long time since there have been so many commits to them. Is there any way of speeding this process up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `--rejoin` option when pushing. After the split is done an extra commit will be created joining the newly created tree with your main repository. Subsequent splits or pushes will take it from there and run faster.